# Why do we need the unit object to be the terminal object in a cartesian monoidal category?

Tags: category-theory

I know almost for all the examples such as ${\mathrm{Set}}$, $\mathrm{Cat}$, e.t.c., with the categorical product being the monoidal tensor product, the unit object is the terminal object. Is this an assumption, or it can be proved that if $(\mathcal{C},\times,I)$ is a monoidal category where $\mathcal{C}$ contains a terminal object, then $I$ has to be terminal? (I tried to prove this but failded.)
If this is only an assumption, is there any other "counterexample"?

Comment: Generalization: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437241/proof-that-the-unit-of-a-cartesian-monoidal-category-is-terminal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $T$ be a terminal object for $\mathcal{C}$.  Then $T\times I\cong T$ since $I$ is the unit of your monoidal structure, but also $T\times I\cong I$ since $T$ is terminal.  So, $I\cong T$ and $I$ is also terminal.

(This is just the usual argument that the unit of a monoid is unique, applied to the monoid of objects of $\mathcal{C}$ up to isomorphism with $\times$ as the operation.)

Comment: Why does terminality of $T$ imply $T \times I \cong I$?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/542911/proving-basic-lemmas-about-categories-with-finite-products-and-terminal-initial.